# Setting Default Nodata burn value with GDAL Rasterize Layer

Tags: gdal, ogr, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to rasterize a layer as follows:

```
attr = 'N_CT'

tif_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM')
raster = tif_driver.Create(path, x_res, y_res, num_bands, gdal.GDT_UInt16)

shp_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
shp_mem = shp_driver .Open('x.shp')

# loop through each layer in shapefile, add to raster band(s)
for idx in len(shp_mem.GetLayerCount()):
  lyr = shp_mem.GetLayer(i)
  gdal.RasterizeLayer(raster, [i+1], lyr, options=['ATTRIBUTE=' + attr])

*Do some raster computations*

# create .TIF
raster = createRaster(shp,'GTiff', path)

# configure band
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
band.Fill(NO_DATA_VALUE)
band.SetNoDataValue(NO_DATA_VALUE)

# write band
band.WriteArray(arr)

raster = None
```

What happens above is I rasterize a shapefile called 'x.shp' based on a field called N_CT (integers)

However, the output contains what I desire but surrounding it is what I imagine is no data (with value 0 - in black).

> I could set my band no_data value to 0. However, is there a way I can
>   change this default (0) to something that I don't need?

[image]

Comment: Try `options=['init=somenumber', 'a_nodata=thesamenumber',  'ATTRIBUTE=' + attr]`. Haven't added as an answer as I can't test.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution. The issue was that I was setting the `band.fill(NO_DATA)` only when creating the final output.

In order to fix this, I simply had to set fill value at the time of rasterizing the layer

Comment: You mean you have put ```band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
band.Fill(NO_DATA_VALUE)``` in front of ```RasterizeLayer```?